# can a LUB be part of an open interval

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

I am re-reading an old textbook "Introduction to Hilbert spaces and applications" by Lokenath Debnath and Piotr Mikusinski, and there is a proof of a lemma in a chapter about the Lebesgue integral that I just can't rap my head around. It's this one:

Lemma 2.2.2.
Let $[a_1,b_1),[a_2,b_2),...$ be disjoint subintervals of an interval $[a,b)$ such that 
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty[a_n,b_n)=[a,b). \tag{2.2.2}$$
Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(b_n-a_n)=b-a. \tag{2.2.3}$$

Proof. Let $S\subset[a,b)$ consist of all points $c$ such that the lemma holds for the interval $[a,c)$ and the sequence of subintervals $[a_n,b_n)\cap[a,c)$. Therefore, if $c\in S$, then
$$c-a=\sum_n(b_{c,n}-a_n),$$
where $b_{c,n}=\min\{b_n,c\}$ and the summation is over all those $n$ for which $a_n \lt b_{c,n}$. It suffices to prove that $b \in S$. To this end we first prove that $\mathbf{LUB}\, S \in S$. Indeed, if $s=\mathbf{LUB}\, S$ and $\{s_n\}$ is an non-decreasing sequence of elelments of $S$ convergent to $s$, then
$$s_n-a=\sum_m(b_{s_n,m}-a_m) \le \sum_m{(b_{s,m}-a_m)} \le s-a. \tag{2.2.4}$$
Since $s_n-a \to s-a$, (2.2.4) implies
$$\sum_m{(b_{s,m}-a_m)}=s-a,$$
and consequently $s \in S$. Next we show that $s=b$. Suppose $s \lt b$. Then 
$$s \in [a_k,b_k) \, \text{ for some } k \in \mathbf{N},$$
and thus $b_k \in S$. Since this contradicts the definition of $s$, we conclude $s=b$. The proof is now complete.

My problem with the proof is the idea that the end point of an open interval can belong to the interval. How can $b \in S$ if $S \subset [a,b)$?

Comment: It can't be. The right universe for $S$ is $[a,b]$, not $[a,b)$. I suspect a simple typo.

Comment: I thought so too, but since the lemma clearly states a semi-open interval (as all other definitions, lemmas and theorems in this chapter,) it does not seem to be mathematical correct to use $S \in [a,b]$. This lemma is a bit esoteric to a non-mathematician, but since the author thinks it is non-trivial , I gather that the details are important.

Comment: Since $b = \sup S$, you cannot have both, $\sup S \in S$ and $S\subset [a,b)$. Saying $S\subset [a,b]$ is the fix with minimal changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a newer edition of the book, the proof has been rewritten. In effect, $S \subset (a,b]$ or $S \subseteq (a,b]$ has replaced the old definition. Sorry for wasting people's time.